# Need to set i as zero everytime the for loop is run in python

Tags: python, for-loop

In the second for loop that runs till 26 I want it to be set back to zero every time an item is removed from the list, so that I can check from the beginning if an alphabet is present in the set of all alphabets in list1.I tried adding i = 0 inside the if statement which is inside the for loop, but it goes back to its range value and does not get reset to zero.

```
import string
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    str1 = string.ascii_lowercase
    list1 = [ ]
    list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    str3 = ""
    str4 = str3.join(lettersGuessed)

    for j in range(len(str4)):
       for i in range(26):
           if list1[i] == str4[i]:
           list1.remove(list1[i])


lettersGuessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
```

Comment: In other words, you want to remove `lettersGuessed` from `string.ascii_lowercase`?

Comment: Generally, without using things specific to Python, you would replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop (`while i < 26` or similar) and add lines to increment/reset `i` as needed. If this is for production coder rather than as a general programming exercise then go with @wim's method.

Comment: Yes, sorry for being ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
import string

def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    return sorted(set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set(lettersGuessed))

lettersGuessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
```

Comment: Thanks!,That was beautiful code.I should think more like this.I guess it comes with practice.

Answer (score 0):

[`for` loops](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) in Python have a lesser-known (and somewhat arcane) `else` expression that can be used to determine if the entire loop completed. It's useful for restarting a loop.

```
for j in range(…):
  while True:
    for i in range(26):
      if list1[i] == str4[i]:
        list1.remove(list1[i])
        break # Break out of the `for` loop to continue the `while`.
    else:
      # The `else` will not happen if we `break` in the `for` loop.
      break # Finished the `for` loop; Break out of the `while`.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `while loop` instead, something like this:

```
i = 0
for j in range(len(str4)):
       while i < 26:
           if list1[i] == str4[i]:
               list1.remove(list1[i])
               i = 0
               continue
           i += 1
```

This way you can actually change the value of `i` and `continue` with the loop from zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    lst= ''
    for e in alphabet:
        if e not in lettersGuessed:
            lst += e 
    return lst
```

This is what I did for any letter not in alphabet, I added it back into a string